# Accessing Vector from another class

Tags: java, class, methods, instances

I have these two classes, named Student and Subject

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Student
{
    int registrationNumber;
    String firstName;
    String familyName;
    Vector<Subject> sub;

    public Student(int registrationNumber,String firstName, String familyName, Subject sub) {
       this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.familyName = familyName;
       this.sub = new Vector<Subject>();
    }

    public Vector<Subject> getSub(){
      return sub;
    }
}
```

and

```
int subjectNumber;
Vector<Double> homeworkMark;
Vector<Double> examinationMark;

public Subject(int subjectNumber) {
    this.subjectNumber = subjectNumber;  
    this.homeworkMark  = new Vector<Double>();
    this.examinationMark = new Vector<Double>();
}


public double homeworkAverage() {
    double homeworkAddition = 0;
    for(Subject y: getSub()){
       for (double s: homeworkMark) {
          homeworkAddition += s;
       }
    }
    return homeworkAddition;
}

public double examinationAverage() {
   double examAddition = 0;
   for(Subject y: getSub()){
     for (double s: examinationMark) {
          examAddition += s;
      }
   }
   return examAddition;
}
```

I'm trying to use my getter method called `getSub()` to perform an addition of the Homeworks and exam marks in all the subjects the user enters, which are stored in the *sub* `Vector`.

My problem is in this loop (also in the similar `examinationAverage()` method

```
public double homeworkAverage() {
      double homeworkAddition = 0;
      for(Subject y: getSub()){
         for (double s: homeworkMark) {
              homeworkAddition += s;
         }
      }
      return homeworkAddition;
 }
```

I tried creating an instance of student, though, it tells me that I have no arguments set, and that I cannot continue...

Any Ideas,

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: can you please post the code where the exception appears? The stachtrace might be helpful!

Comment: i get an error on getSub() in the method homeworkAverage() because it says the method cannot be found. The method is in the Student class, but i dont know how im going to access it from the subject class.

Comment: @where is the homeworkAverage called?

Comment: the method homeworkAverage is in the main method, when i want to caslculate the average, but, i get an error on getSub().

Comment: see my answer...you can continue with comments under it if still questions remain

Answer (score 0):

Their are 2 stranges things for me:

- you pass a `Subject` parameter in the `Student` constructor but don't use it
- the getSub() method is in the `Student` class but is accessed from `Subject` neither on a given Student instance nor in a static way.

Comment: that's my problem. I dont know how to access getSub() WHen i create an instance of type student in my subject class, I get an error saying I need to set arguements for student...

Comment: or i get a null pointer exception if i just do "Student stud;"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are instantiating your Student class with an initial Subject argument "sub"? In this case you are missing to add the "sub" argument to the Vector:

```
public Student(int registrationNumber,String firstName, String familyName, Subject sub) {
   this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.familyName = familyName;
   this.sub = new Vector<Subject>();
   this.sub.add(sub); // <-- here
}
```

Otherwise the sub argument is discarded...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

- in order to call a method of a given object you must have the object first hand, so in your case something like this:

  ```
  public double homeworkAverage() {
     double homeworkAddition = 0;
     for(Subject y: student.getSub()){ //....
  ```

  from what you posted, one cannot realize where the `homeworkAverage` is declared/used but you could make it **static** and provide provide a `Student` parameter:

  ```
  public static double homeworkAverage(Student student) {
     double homeworkAddition = 0;
     for (Subject y : student.getSub()) { ....
  ```

I hope it sheds some light